# How to Optimize the Sitecore Images

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I would like to Optimize the Sitecore Images and I found a documentation but I struck out on the first line itself

1. Install the packages with the /sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx

I found the path but could not find UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx,may I know what should I do to get that aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to navigate to this page just using the url `http://localhost/sitecore/admin/updateinstallationwizard.aspx`.

You should first see the login screen and after you login, you should see the wizard.

You can also see the blog post [Easy Access to the Update Installation Wizard](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2013/january/easyupdateinstallationwizard.aspx)

Comment: The [Sitecore Developer Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sitecore-developer-tool/cmbppbejihcnbngefandoljljdppnlda) Chrome extension is really useful for these shortcuts. More info on this [Sitecore blog post](https://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Integration-Solution-Team-blog/Posts/2014/09/Sitecore-Developer-Tool-for-Google-Chrome.aspx).